# Does Mailgun.js offer the possibility to send a template?

Tags: node.js, email, mailgun, mailing

So [MailGun](https://www.mailgun.com) offers the possibility to send email via their Node library that implements their [API](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/api-sending.html):

```
var mailgun = require('mailgun-js')({ apiKey: api_key, domain: DOMAIN });

var filepath = path.join(__dirname, 'sample.jpg');

var data = {
  from: 'Excited User <me@samples.mailgun.org>',
  to: 'foo@example.com, baz@example.com, bar@example.com',
  cc: 'baz@example.com',
  bcc: 'bar@example.com',
  subject: 'Complex',
  text: 'Testing some Mailgun awesomness!',
  html: "<html>HTML version of the body</html>",
  attachment: filepath
};

mailgun.messages().send(data, function (error, body) {
  console.log(body);
});
```

And they also offer the possibility to design and create [Email Templates](https://www.mailgun.com/email-templates). Is there any way to send templated emails with some custom variables via their API? Something like:

```
var data = {
  from: 'Excited User <me@samples.mailgun.org>',
  to: 'foo@example.com, baz@example.com, bar@example.com',

  template: "withdraw_request_approved", //Instead of 'html'
  vars: { firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe' }
};

mailgun.messages().send(data, function (error, body) {
  console.log(body);
});
```

If not, could you suggest some other mailing service that offer this kind of functionality? (I've skipped [Mandrill](https://mandrill.com/) since it's apparently currently down, with no clear estimate to when it'll become available again)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, you can, following would be the format in your case:

```
var data = {
  from: 'Excited User <me@samples.mailgun.org>',
  to: 'foo@example.com, baz@example.com, bar@example.com',

  template: "withdraw_request_approved", //Instead of 'html'
  'v:firstName': 'John',
  'v:lastName': 'Doe'
};
```

Comment: thx, you're a life saver! I was so keep trying "h:X-Mailgun-Variables" as per docs but it did not work at all!

Comment: You are a lifesaver for me! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

According to [Mailgun Template Documentation](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/user_manual.html#templates) you can pass template data using any of the 2 options provided below,

**Option 1**

```
var data = {
  from: 'Excited User <me@samples.mailgun.org>',
  to: 'alice@example.com',
  subject: 'Hello',
  template: 'template.test',
  h:X-Mailgun-Variables: '{"title": "API Documentation", "body": "Sending messages with templates"}'
};
```

In this example `h:X-Mailgun-Variables` this is the tricky bit which I achieved updating my object like this.

```
var data = {
  from: 'Excited User <me@samples.mailgun.org>',
  to: 'alice@example.com',
  subject: 'Hello',
  template: 'template.test',
  'h:X-Mailgun-Variables': JSON.stringify({
    title: "API Documentation",
    body: "Sending messages with templates"
  })
};
```

**Option 2**

Though this is already explained in a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55428363/2117868), I am addition this for completeness.

```
var data = {
  from: 'Excited User <me@samples.mailgun.org>',
  to: 'alice@example.com',
  subject: 'Hello',
  template: 'template.test',
  'v:title': 'API Documentation',
  'v:body': 'Sending messages with templates'
};
```

Finally, according to their documentation

> The second way (*Option 2* in our case) is not recomended as it’s limited to simple key value
>   data. If you have arrays, dictionaries in values or complex json data
>   you have to supply variables via `X-Mailgun-Variables` header.